# Axure not adding viewport tag to HTML

Tags: viewport, axure

I have set up the Generate HTML settings so that the viewport width="device-width" tag is added to generated HTML.

[image]
When viewing the generated HTML, the viewport meta tag is missing:

[image]

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is a bug in Axure 7. You must specify "Without Sitemap" in the Preview Options in order to get this to work. It won't work if you choose "With Sitemap" or "With Sitemap Minimised". Annoying bug and will hopefully get fixed soon.

[image]